# Trying to understand caching when data is dynamic?

Tags: caching, users

I have a content type with a field called: "secretword".

When viewing the page, I have logic in the tpl.php file that determines if this field is going to be shown to the user. The logic for whether it must be shown is quite complex (calls a web server, calls another, does a calc etc, so having roles for each condition doesn't make sense). My concern is that if I calculate the field in the tpl page, that somehow somewhere along the line the page is going to be cached. Or perhaps indexed in the search directory for prying eyes to find.

So I need:

- any user to access a node
- each user to see a guaranteed new version of the page with their personally calculated "Secretword", including in search results etc
- no cached values for these nodes ever for any prying eyes to find

How can I display nodes securely, knowing that the data on the page won't be cached and will remain well-hidden in search results?

**UPDATE**

Would setting up a rule that if you access content not passing a certain PHP condition, forwards that user to a access denied page?

Comment: Template files should not contains any logic like that. Why are you using nodes instead of a custom module showing a page?

Comment: I was hoping to use nodes, because all the other rules still apply. I.e. I need to make various instances of data, and all that changes is what is shown depending on the user?

Comment: Even in the case the module would require to read a value from the database, and that value depends from the logged-in user, that is something a module can easily do. If, for any reason, you still need to use nodes, then you can implement a custom field. Those options are better than putting something in a theme, especially when the functionality should not depend from the theme being used.

Comment: Put the logic for the field in an AJAX callback. The main page can then be cached, and the page will make an AJAX request to the server that will run the conditional logic and return the result.